# Python append value at array increment to a list

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of lists:

```
name_list = ['John', 'Smith'], ['Sarah', 'Nichols'], ['Alex', 'Johnson']
```

I have another arbitrary list, let's say of colors:

```
color_list = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']
```

What's the simplest or most efficient way of appending a given number of colors to the names in rotation? For example, if I chose two colors the returned list would look like:

```
output_list = ['John', 'Smith', 'Red'], ['Sarah', 'Nichols', 'Green'], ['Alex', 'Johnson', 'Red']
```

or if I chose 3 colors:

```
output_list = ['John', 'Smith', 'Red'], ['Sarah', 'Nichols', 'Green'], ['Alex', 'Johnson', 'Blue']
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `itertools.cycle` a slice of the list:

```
name_list = [['John', 'Smith'], ['Sarah', 'Nichols'], ['Alex', 'Johnson']]


color_list = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']

from itertools import cycle, islice

i = 2 
cyc =  cycle(islice(color_list, 0, i))
for  sub in name_list:
    sub.append(next(cyc))


print(name_list)
```

Output:

```
[['John', 'Smith', 'Red'], ['Sarah', 'Nichols', 'Green'], ['Alex', 'Johnson', 'Red']]
```

You could also use the index as we iterate over `name_list` modulo `i` to extract the correct element from `color_list`:

```
name_list = [['John', 'Smith'], ['Sarah', 'Nichols'], ['Alex', 'Johnson'], ['Alex', 'Johnson']]

color_list = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']


i = 2
for ind, sub in enumerate(name_list):
    sub.append(color_list[ind % i])

print(name_list)
```

Comment: @Pynchia, I had two answers and ended up mixing up both, enumerate is not needed at all for the first

Answer (score 0):

First - your list of lists should look like this:

```
name_list = [['John', 'Smith'], ['Sarah', 'Nichols'], ['Alex', 'Johnson']]
```

you are missing the brackets...

one simple way would be to use modulo operator... (check for edge cases such as when color list is empty):

```
color_len = len(color_list)
for idx,elem in enumerate(name_list):
    elem.append( color_list[idx%color_len] )
```